# how to programatically set showCheckbox on childnodes within a asp.net treeview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

all I am trying to figure out how to set a checkbox to a child node within an asp.net webform via code.

my method:

```
protected void CreateTreeViewList(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel p, ICollection<Agency> a)
        {
            TreeView agencyTreeView = new TreeView();

            var results = a;

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item.AgencyName);

               // var myagencies = item.SecurityDataShares1;

                Array entityList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Entities));

                foreach (var ei in entityList)
                {
                   node.ShowCheckBox = true;
                   node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(ei.ToString()));
               }

                node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode());

                agencyTreeView.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
            p.Controls.Add(agencyTreeView);
        }
```

This is my first shot at a treeview control so it may be off a bit (any tips would be appreciated).

Where I am stuck is on the nested foreach I can get the nodes to render out (entity List is just an Array of 10 text elements). I can't seem to figure out how to have a show textbox assigned

I tried

```
node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(ei.ToString()).ShowCheckbox = true);
```

While intellisense supported it the compiler threw and error.

Also as a side note I notice that the checkbox list shows the nodes as links is there a way to disable this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I discovered the TreeNodeTypes property

Adding the following line to the end of the method below or before the `p.Controls.Add(agencyTreeView)`

added check boxes to each child node

```
agencyTreeView.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.Leaf;
```

Hope this helps anyone interested